# Растянуть div на всю ширину страницы

Tags: html, css

При создании блока, я растянул его на 100%, но на странице он имеет отступы со всех сторон, ставлю margin, отступ пропадает, тк блок уходит за страницу, но появляется нижний скролл и страница становится шире

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEFF0;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border: 70px solid;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: -2%;
  margin-top: -2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list"></div>
  <nav><a href="#">Каталог</a><a href="#">Контакты</a></nav>
</div>
```

Comment: покажите код ...

Comment: Добавил код в вопросе

Comment: border: 70px solid; а бордер в 70px - это необходимость?

Answer (score 2):

> `box-sizing: border-box` говорит браузеру учитывать любые границы и внутренние отступы в значениях, которые вы указываете в ширине и высоте элемента. Если вы выставите элементу ширину 100 пикселей, то эти 100 пикселей будут включать в себя границы и внутренние отступы, а контент сожмётся, чтобы выделить для них место. Обычно это упрощает работу с размерами элементов.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EDEFF0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border: 70px solid;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list"></div>
  <nav><a href="#">Каталог</a><a href="#">Контакты</a></nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили)

Answer (score 0):

Скачай Normalize.css, если же обнуления присутствуют, то значит ты сделал wrapper внутри контейнера, либо задал отступы для body
Или же:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```